# can't get ilmerge to work

Tags: ilmerge

Im trying to include 1 exe and 3 dll's into a single exe file using ilmerge.

I can run the normal exe file, if the 3 dll's are in the same folder. So I know the program is working as intended.

I then use ilmerge like this:

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:Run.exe IncidentReportGenerator.exe 
iTextSharp.dll Newtonsoft.Json.dll RestSharp.dll  
/targetplatform:v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

This completes without errors and im left with the Run.exe (and Run.pdb).
But when i now double click on Run.exe nothing happens.

In taskmng Run.exe shows up, and disaperes again after 5-6 sec.
IncidentReportGenerator.exe is a console application. Double clicking this opens a console, as mentioned before.

Anyone have a idea, why this dosen't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try this [tool](http://ilmergertool.codeplex.com/releases)  with GUI interface